Getting Value in Streamlit Element not linked to Variable
As part of my code, I create a text input for each field within my table using a loop and I assign each of them a key. How would I retrieve the values entered in those text inputs since I do not have a variable name associated with them? I imagine I would utilize the session state, is that correct?
Here is the code I am utilizing to query my database, get the field names from my collection, and create text inputs for each field. How would I refer to these text boxes to get their value?
def cols(db,s_box):

    fields =[]
    exclude = ['notes']

    cursor = db.get_collection(s_box).find({})

    for item in cursor:
        for i in item:
            if i not in exclude:
                fields.append(i)
                st.sidebar.text_input("Please enter a search value for {}".format(i),key=i)

